# Get 2 rows from a table having same column values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, limit

TABLE

```
id      m_id             image
1        1               img1.jpg
2        2               img2.jpg
3        1               img11.jpg
4        2               img22.jpg
5        1               img111.jpg

........ etc
```

What i need is - Get only 2 rows from the table group by m_id as below

```
//here getting images where m_id=1 and it is not more than 2
<section class='test'>
     <div class="n-2">
       <img src='img1.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class="n-2">
       <img src='img11.jpg'>
     </div>
</section>


//next fetching images with m_id=2
<section class='test'>
     <div class="n-2">
       <img src='img2.jpg'>
     </div>
     <div class="n-2">
       <img src='img22.jpg'>
     </div>
</section>
  ......
```

What i tried is

```
<?php
 $query=$db->query("Select * from gallery order by m_id asc");
 $result = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i+=2) { 
    ?>
       <section class='test'>
     <div class="n-2">
       <img src='<?php $result[$i]['image']; ?>'>
     </div>
     <div class="n-2">
       <img src='<?php $result[$i+1]['image']; ?>'>
     </div>
     </section>
   <?php
   }
?>
```

But i am getting all the fields to the showed `section class'test'`, How to get the only 2 rows as showed section class.

Any experts?

Comment: use limit = 2 on your query

Comment: limit will give loop 2 times , what if i have 30 rows ?

Comment: @teashark m_id is 3 times not 2.

Comment: Try this select * from employee where emp_dept IN(select emp_dept from employee  group by emp_dept having count(emp_dept ) > 1)

Comment: I tried this, but this shows all rows which having more than 1 matches. I need to limit it to 2

Answer (score 0):

Hi this query will get you only two record
you should read the MySql tutorials in [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com)

```
Select * from gallery order by m_id asc LIMIT 2
```

Update 1: this will work hopefully in your case.

```
$query = $db->query("Select * from gallery order by m_id asc");
$items = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$result = [];
$temp = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $m_id = $item['m_id'];
    if (!isset($temp[$m_id]) || count($temp[$m_id]) < 2) {
        $temp[$m_id][] = $item['image'];
        $result = $item['image'];
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i += 2) {
    ?>
    <section class='test'>
        <div class="n-2">
            <img src='<?php $result[$i]['image']; ?>'>
        </div>
        <div class="n-2">
            <img src='<?php $result[$i + 1]['image']; ?>'>
        </div>
    </section>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Already tried limit 2, it wont solve the issue. The limit 2 just stop the loop  when iterate 2 times, which is not required solution

Comment: Sorry for late, i will check now

Comment: Unfortunately This not retrieving any rows. What is the use of extra code you done here  rather than mine

Comment: you can use var_dump function for debugging. for example after line 2 write var_dump($items); die;